# How to write an online file using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a program that uses javascript. I searched online for a while, but only saw ways on how to read a file. Is it possible to write to a file on my website using javascript? Like if I wanted to add a line to it that say "hi" or something like that. Thanks!

Comment: yes ... but it requires server side code as well

Comment: Do you have an example or docs where I can see it?

Comment: well, there are many server side languages - which one will you be using to do this?

Comment: the hosted file is in php

Comment: hmm, can't find any plain javascript answers on SO - perhaps you'll have better luck searching

Comment: May I suggest you look up for PHP solutions to your problem, most likely find one and so remove your question, or in the event that StackOverflow and the PHP documentation are not enough, rewrite your question?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot read/write from/to server using client-side Javascript. You need a server-side language(which can be Javascript or any other language like PHP or Java) to do that. The best you can do is expose a REST service which wille write the content passed to it, to a file and call that REST service from your client-side Javascript code. Pass the content you want to write in this service call and then write that content to the filesystem